# Swift Protocols: Difference between extensions protocols

Tags: swift

Given this Swift code using protocols

```
class Class1: NSObject, FirstProtocol 
{
   // Class1 implementation
}

class Class2: NSObject, FirstProtocol, SecondProtocol
{

   // Class2 implementation  
}

protocol FirstProtocol {
   func foo1 () 
}

extension FirstProtocol {
   func foo1 ()
   {
     // implementation of foo1
   }
}

protocol SecondProtocol: FirstProtocol {
   func foo1 ()
   func foo2 ()
}

extension SecondProtocol where Self: Class2 {
   func foo2 ()
   {
      // implementation foo2 
   }
}
```

Can anyone tell me the purpose of "where Self: Class2" in this code?

My bet is that the extension to Class2 in the SecondProtocol is restricted only for Class2 implementation.

I am right?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but it doesn't make a whole lot of sense for `foo1` to be a declared function in the `SecondProtocol` as it is already declared in the `FirstProtocol`, which `SecondProtocol` inherits from.

Answer (score 0):

The last extension means that you are writing a default implementation of `foo2` for any type conforming to `SecondProtocol` subject to the condition that `Self: Class2` i.e. you are extending any subclasses of `Class2` that conform to `SecondProtocol`. Since `Class2` conforms to `SecondProtocol`, all subclasses of `Class2` conform to `SecondProtocol`. Consequently, this extension somewhat unnecessary — it is the same thing as an extension to `Class2`.

You are better off moving the implemention of `foo2` directly into `Class2` or into an extension of `Class2`.

Comment: A more interesting extension would be `extension SecondProtocol where Self: Class1`. This would extend all subclasses of `Class1` which conform to `SecondProtocol`, including `Class2` and possibly others.